# ui-route not redirecting to external page

Tags: angularjs, redirect, angular-ui-router

From a modal dialog I present a *general terms* link that should redirect the user to a new page.
I would like to re-use my layout skeleton (background, logo ans basic styles) for the terms page, without the content of the master page (eg. search function, navigation etc).
 To achieve this I try to inject into a new window the terms template inside the **ui-view="main"** used for the normal site content (where is loaded the content of the modal dialog, as instance), but I get the error *Could not resolve 'terms' from state 'login'* (login is the current state where the modal dialog is).

Below the termsPage module with the ui-router state I would like to load:

```
angular.module('termsPage').config(function ($stateProvider) {
$stateProvider
    .state('terms', {
        url: '/terms',
        views: {
            'main': {
                controller: 'TermsCtrl as Terms',
                templateUrl: '/modules/staticPages/views/termsPage.html'
            }
        }
    });
});
```

My index.html file:

```
<!-- Other tags excluded for sake of semplicity -->
<body ng-app="myApp">

   <!-- Here I inject all the content -->
   <div id="wrapper" ui-view="main"> 
</div>
```

Below the app module and view, where the content of the application is correctly loaded. Also the modal dialog from which I would like to redirect to the external page is loaded here.

```
angular.module('app').config(function($stateProvider){
    $stateProvider
        .state('app', {
            url: '/app',
            views:{
                'main' : {
                    controller : 'AppCtrl',
                    templateUrl: 'modules/app/views/app.html'
                }
            }
        });
});
```

Below app.html:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="browser">
     <div class="content" ui-view="content" style="position:relative;">
  </div>
```

My goal would be to create a *sibling* of app.html, injecting in main placeholder the content of my general terms page. Inside the modal dialog controller I use $state.go for the redirection:

```
$state.go('terms');
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that I did not registered the new module ('termsPage') as dependency in my main module:

angular.module(**'myApp'**, ['login','forms',**'termsPage'**], function($urlRouterProvider){ ...}

Now that the module is registered, I can navigate correctly to state 'terms'.
Hopefully the case above might help someone else, getting hints for his/her case.